# Slow prediction speed for translation model opus-mt-en-ro

Tags: deep-learning, huggingface-transformers, machine-translation

I'm using the model [Helsinki-NLP/opus-mt-en-ro](https://huggingface.co/Helsinki-NLP/opus-mt-en-ro) from huggingface.
To produce output, I'm using the following code:

```
    inputs = tokenizer(
            questions,
            max_length=max_input_length,
            truncation=True,
            return_tensors='pt',
            padding=True).to('cuda')
    translation = model.generate(**inputs)
```

For small inputs (i.e. the number of sentences in `questions`), it works fine. However, when the number of sentences increases (e.g., batch size = 128), it is very slow.
I have a dataset of 100K examples and I have to produce the output. How to make it faster? (I already checked the usage of GPU and it varies between 25% and 70%).

Update: Following the comment of dennlinger, here is the additional information:

- Average question length: Around 30 tokens
- Definition of slowness: With a batch of 128 questions, it takes around 25 seconds. So given my dataset of 100K examples, it will take more than 5 hours. I'm using GPU Nvidia V100 (16GB) (hence `to('cuda')` in the code). I cannot increase the batch size because it results in `out of memory` error.
- I didn't try different parameters, but I know by default, the number of beams equals 1.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. How long are your questions on average (or what is the difference in potential lengths)? What is your current average throughput (i.e., what constitutes as "slow")? Have you played with any of the generation parameters (number of beams, etc.)? And is your model also on the GPU (you should probably get an error otherwise)? What is your available GPU memory/GPU type?

Comment: @dennlinger I updated the question. I wonder if the method `generate` I used is the best one? Is there any other function that can do the job? I tried with `predict` but the model doesn't have that function.

Comment: Generate is definitely the right way to go. Given your additional details, I'm not sure if it is so slow (200 ms per sentence seems a reasonable latency for BERT-based models), so unfortunately I don't see an easy way to scale this without more GPUs....

Comment: Helsinki-NLP models were originally trained in Marian and then converted to Huggingface Transformers. Marian is a specialized tool for MT and is very fast. If you do not need the internals of the models and only need the translation, it should be a better choice.

Comment: You need to transfer the model to the gpu. device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"), then model=model.to(device).